# Wildfly 26.1.3: Can't start project: WFLYCTL0080: NullPointerException

Tags: java, java-8, wildfly-26

I'm trying to start project in **Wildfly 26.1.3**, using **Java 8** (JDK 1.8.0_321) and **Primefaces 6**, but I'm getting **WFLYCTL0080 (*NullPointerException*)** error. When I use **Wildfly 8.2.1** everything works fine.

When I execute **standalone.sh**:

```
=========================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: /c/Users/herbert.reis/Documents/wildfly-26.1.3.Final
  JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321/bin/java
  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true
=========================================================================
....
....
....
16:57:00,133 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] 
(ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
16:57:00,475 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) Inicializando Mojarra 2.3.17.SP01 para o contexto '/ssabd'
16:57:01,238 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
16:57:01,238 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at javax.faces.application.Application.getSearchExpressionHandler(Application.java:1911)
16:57:01,238 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.getSearchExpressionHandler(ApplicationWrapper.java:841)
16:57:01,238 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.setSearchExpressionHandler(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:624)
16:57:01,239 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:320)
16:57:01,239 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.lambda$initialize$0(ConfigManager.java:295)
16:57:01,239 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
16:57:01,239 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
16:57:01,239 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
16:57:01,239 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:293)
16:57:01,239 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:207)
16:57:01,239 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
16:57:01,239 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
16:57:01,240 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
16:57:01,240 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
16:57:01,240 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
16:57:01,240 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
16:57:01,240 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
16:57:01,240 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
16:57:01,240 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
16:57:01,240 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
16:57:01,240 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
16:57:01,240 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:105)
16:57:01,240 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
16:57:01,241 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
16:57:01,241 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
16:57:01,241 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
16:57:01,241 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
16:57:01,241 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
16:57:01,241 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
16:57:01,241 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
16:57:01,241 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85)   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
16:57:01,800 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) Critical error during deployment: : java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate$PostConstructApplicationListener.processEvent(ApplicationAssociate.java:324)
        at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:123)
        at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Events.processListeners(Events.java:253)
        at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Events.invokeListenersFor(Events.java:231)
        at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Events.publishEvent(Events.java:112)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:127)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.jsf.ForwardingApplication.publishEvent(ForwardingApplication.java:282)
        at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:788)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(ConfigManager.java:548)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:266)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)

16:57:01,803 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ssabd.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ssabd.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:90)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:257)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:286)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate$PostConstructApplicationListener.processEvent(ApplicationAssociate.java:324)
        at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:123)
        at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Events.processListeners(Events.java:253)
        at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Events.invokeListenersFor(Events.java:231)
        at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Events.publishEvent(Events.java:112)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:127)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.jsf.ForwardingApplication.publishEvent(ForwardingApplication.java:282)
        at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:788)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(ConfigManager.java:548)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:266)
        ... 21 more

16:57:01,809 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "ssabd.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"ssabd.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
16:57:01,897 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "ssabd.war" (runtime-name : "ssabd.war")
16:57:01,898 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "ssabd-ds.xml" (runtime-name : "ssabd-ds.xml")
16:57:01,902 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."ssabd.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
WFLYCTL0448: 1 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed
16:57:02,023 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
16:57:02,027 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 26.1.3.Final (WildFly Core 18.1.2.Final) started (with errors) in 20089ms - Started 1216 of 1400 services (3 services failed or missing dependencies, 345 services are lazy, passive or on-demand) - Server configuration file in use: standalone.xml
16:57:02,030 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
16:57:02,030 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
```

**ssabd-ds.xml** file:

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/ssabd" pool-name="ssabd" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ssabd</connection-url>
        <driver>postgresql</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>postgres</user-name>
            <password>admin</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
</datasources>
```

**persistence.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="ssabd" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/jboss/ssabd</jta-data-source>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="180" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="100" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**ssabd.war.failed** file:

```
"{\"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"ssabd.war\\\".undertow-deployment\" => \"java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException\"}}"
```

What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Thats something normally happens when a JSF 2.3+ API is in the classpath but JSF 2.2 impl is used in background.